# Reading the roaming state or network operator of iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, roaming

Is it possible to receive an event when an iPhone device connects to roaming, or changes the network operator so that I can read the new operator name and display it to the user. For example just like some cars tablet displays display the network operator name of the phone they are connected with.

I've read from multiple sources that it is not possible to read the roaming state of the sim card, so reading the operator name of the currently connected network will be sufficient